# issue with specifying name while sending mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, postfix-mta

My code:--

```
from = @site.name + ", <no-reply@" + @site.url + ">"
mail(:from => from , :to => @recipient.email, :subject => "Invitation mail")
```

Error is:--

```
 Net::SMTPSyntaxError (501 5.1.7 Bad sender address syntax 
):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the comma between `@site.name` and your `<` bracket. You're trying to do this:

```
My Name, <no-reply@mysite.com>
```

When it should be:

```
My Name <no-reply@mysite.com>
```

Comment: Are you sure `@site.name` and `@site.url` are evaluating properly? Maybe stick a `Rails.logger.info "From Address: #{from}"` before your `mail(...)` call and take a look at your logs to see the exact result of your `from` field?